# How to implement poll() using KafkaConsumer?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am running a daemon which push 500 records on every 5 sec interval into Kafka.

I am using KafkaConsumer to pull records from Kafka. I write a consumer code in Python3 to pull only 100 records and consumer won't wait more than 8 sec. I am using poll() method in this case. But below code is not returning 100 records instead it's returning newly added 500 records from Kafka. Could you let me know what's the wrong with code? Do you suggest an alternative approach to achieve my requirement.

```
consumer= KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_server,
              group_id=consumergroup,
              client_id=consumerid,
              enable_auto_commit=False,
              auto_offset_reset='latest', 
              value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('ascii')))
              
consumer.subscribe("mytopic")
consumer.poll(8000, 100, True)

for message in consumer: 
   print("offset", message.offset)
```

Thanks

Comment: The for loop automatically calls poll in the background. You dont need to call it manually

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call poll() manually, it will be called automatically in the for loop.
If you need to specify the number of each batch, specify the parameter max_poll_records=100 when generating a consumer."max_poll_records" default 500.

```
consumer= KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_server,
          max_poll_records=100,#like this
          group_id=consumergroup,
          client_id=consumerid,
          enable_auto_commit=False,
          auto_offset_reset='latest', 
          value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('ascii')))
```

Comment: I tried that way also. I am not getting 100 records in each batch instead of I am getting all latest records approx. 500 records in each batch.

Comment: Your scenario is to push 500 records to Kafka every five seconds. I think your program cannot distinguish between batches of messages. You can use message = consumer.poll() to manually poll the message for verification.

Comment: I tried as below approach but it did not work. Am I doing something wrong?

consumer= KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_server,
              group_id=consumergroup,
              client_id=consumerid,
              enable_auto_commit=False,
              auto_offset_reset='latest', 
              value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('ascii')))
              
consumer.subscribe("mytopic")
consumer.poll(8000, 100, True)

for message in consumer: 
   print("offset", message.offset)

Comment: 1. Enter the poll() method, you will find the following description:
   “Incompatible with iterator interface -- use one or the other, not both.”
2. poll should be called cyclically, check for details:
https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/1139

Comment: I set max_records=50, timeout_ms=500ms. According to me consumer should wait for 500ms then exit if data isn't available. But it's not working as expected, consumer hangs if topic is empty. 

[code]
while True:
        msg_pack = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=500, max_records=50)
        for tp, messages in msg_pack.items():
            for message in messages:
                  print ("%s:offset :%d: key=%s value=%s" % (tp.topic,
                                                      message.offset, message.key,
                                                      message.value))
[code]